# What is causing this LazyRepositoryLocation - Cannot find repository error?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.2

```
12:39:13.932 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] ERROR c.s.c.config.LazyRepositoryLocation - Cannot find repository at ../repository : File ../repository does not exist at path /Z:/Source Code/DXA-SDL-GitHub/dxa-web-application-java/dxa-example-webapp/target/dxa-example-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/../repository
```

When I start my DXA 1.2 JAVA box (in IntelliJ) I get this LazyRepositoryLocation error in the log. What could cause this?

It looks like the context engine which looks for it's device repository, but I am building the webapp without the CID-module profile.

Context in the log:

```
Jan 05, 2016 12:39:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
12:39:13.932 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] ERROR c.s.c.config.LazyRepositoryLocation - Cannot find repository at ../repository : File ../repository does not exist at path /Z:/Source Code/DXA-SDL-GitHub/dxa-web-application-java/dxa-example-webapp/target/dxa-example-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/../repository
12:39:18.757 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] WARN  o.d.databind.builder.BaseDataBinder - Setting meta key to default: viewName
12:39:18.765 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] WARN  o.d.databind.builder.BaseDataBinder - No package root configured for view models. Using the default package: org.dd4t.web.models
Jan 05, 2016 12:39:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'DispatcherServlet'
```

Answer (score 2):

DXA JAVA depends on the CID and CWD. The `dxa-parent` pom, `dxa-tridion-provider` pom and DXA Tridion provider spring context in `dxa-framework\dxa-tridion-provider\src\main\resources\META-INF\spring-context.xml` have a dependency on the following libs.

- CWD Engine
- CWD cartridge
- CWD resource
- CWD Image

By removing those dependencies (remove a line from the spring conext and removing the 4 CWD dependencies in the mentioned poms) the error and the two warnings are solved. This is is not a permanent fix since the webapp will not work with the CID profile anymore.

I would expect that the web application does not load anything from CID or CWD if the CID profile is not enabled. However, there is a hard dependency.

Comment: Even if CID is not used, the DXA framework still uses the CWD Context Engine in order to do server-side responsiveness.

Comment: Good point, CID is not the same as CWD, but both are part of SDL Mobile. Should there not be a way to tell the webapp not to start looking for the CWD device database? And what about licensing?